# Question about evaluating differential forms on (non)-basis vectors.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, exterior-algebra, tangent-spaces

Let's assume $M$ is a smooth $n$-dimensional manifold and $\omega$ is a differential $k$-form on $M$, then i know that $\omega$ can be expressed as $$\omega = \sum_{\mu_1<\cdots<\mu_k}\omega_{\mu_1\cdots \mu_k}dx^{\mu_1}\wedge...\wedge dx^{\mu_k}$$

Where $\omega_{\mu_1\cdots \mu_k} = \omega\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu_1}},...,\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu_k}}\right)$ are the components of $\omega$ w.r.t the canonical basis $\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu_i}}\right\}$ of $T_pM$.

When I came across the definition of the wedge product, I noticed that I do not know how such differential form $\omega$ evaluates at an arbitrary vector $(v_1,...,v_n) \in T_pM$, i.e. I don't know what

$$\omega(v_1,...,v_n)$$ is supposed to look like.

One of my books states that if $\omega$ is an alternating $k$-form (not a differential form) on the finite dimensional vector space $V$, then $\omega(v_1,...,v_n)$ is the determinant of the metric matrix with entries $\langle v_i,e_i\rangle$ where $e_i$ are the canonical basis vectors. However, on a general smooth manifold, i don't necessarily have an inner product $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ on $T_pM$.

---

**Question 1:**

Assume I'm given a $1$-form $\omega$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such as $$\omega = 2xdx - 3ydy,$$ am I correct if I assume that $2x = \omega\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)$ and $ -3y = \omega\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)$ where $\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right\}$ is the canonical basis of $T_p\mathbb{R}^2 \cong \mathbb{R}^2$ corresponding to the canonical basis $\{e_1,e_2\}$?

**Question 2:**

If that's the case, how would $\omega(v)$ for arbitrary (non-basis) element of $T_p\mathbb{R}^2$ look like?

---

The background for these questions is that when I came across the definition of the wedge product

$\omega\wedge \mu(v_1,...,v_{r+s})$ I noticed that I did not know what $\omega(v_1,...,v_r)$ respectively $\mu(v_{r+1},...,v_{r+s})$ look like.

I hope someone could clarify whether I'm on the right track or where I'm confusing things.

Comment: For your second question: $\omega$ is a $1$-form, hence it cannot take two vectors in entry but only one. Moreover, it may be a typo, but in your first question, $\omega(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}) = -3y$, not $3y$.

Comment: Hello @Didier, thanks for the comment. Yes, that was indeed a typo. Also, you're right of course, i should have either taken a $2$-form $\omega$, or asked for $\omega(v)$, i will fix that.

Comment: For (2) unless there is some special property you can use, you need to either change the basis in which the vectors are expressed, or the basis in which the differential form is written, so that one basis is the dual of the other, then you know how to calculate.